# Php if else with html

Tags: php

Any help with figuring out why I get 'else' (T_ELSE) in your code on line in the code below?

```
 <?php if ( is_category( '3' ) )  ?>
        <td class="logo-alts"><a href="/"><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/_images/image1.png"></a></td>

  <?php if ( is_category( '1096' ) )  ?>
        <td class="logo-alts"><a href="/"><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/_images/image2.png"></a></td>

  <?php if ( is_category( '1437' ) )  ?>
        <td class="logo-alts"><a href="/"><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/_images/image3.png"></a></td>

  <?php if ( is_category( '1150' ) )  ?>
        <td class="logo-alts"><a href="/"><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/_images/image4.png"></a></td>

  <?php if ( is_category( '1138' ) )  ?>
        <td class="logo-alts"><a href="/"><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/_images/image.png"></a></td>

  <?php if ( is_category( '3' ) )  ?>
        <td class="logo-alts"><a href="/"><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/_images/image5.png"></a></td>

  <?php else : ?>
        <td class="logo-alts"><a href="/"><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/_images/image6.png"></a></td>
    <?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: you need to use `:` after the closing `)` with this `if` usage.

Comment: I don't like this "if" usage, there are so many "<?php . . . ?>. Why not a "switch" with an "echo" for each "case"?

Comment: Actually your code seems too bit really redundant, you should shrink it a lot, @user3512391

Comment: @JoseManuelAbarcaRodríguez Yeah that sounds good. But wouldn't it cause issues when echoing a relative url? As in the echo is a wordpress function. Wouldn't I have to hard code the img src url to make the echo work?

Comment: @user3512391, the idea is to remove so many "<?php . . . ?>". The rest of your code remains almost the same. But, if this style works for you, stick to it!

Comment: @bemontibeller although I didn't specify, they will be getting different images depending on the category checked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Format your IF statement like so:

```
      <?php if (is_category('3')) : ?>
            <td class="logo-alts"><a href="/"><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/_images/image.png"></a></td>

      <?php elseif (is_category('1096')) : ?>
            <td class="logo-alts"><a href="/"><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/_images/image.png"></a></td>

      <?php elseif (is_category('1437')) : ?>
            <td class="logo-alts"><a href="/"><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/_images/image.png"></a></td>

      <?php elseif (is_category('1150')) : ?>
            <td class="logo-alts"><a href="/"><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/_images/image.png"></a></td>

      <?php elseif (is_category('1138')) : ?>
            <td class="logo-alts"><a href="/"><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/_images/image.png"></a></td>

      <?php elseif (is_category('3')) : ?>
            <td class="logo-alts"><a href="/"><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/_images/image.png"></a></td>

      <?php else : ?>
            <td class="logo-alts"><a href="/"><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/_images/image.png"></a></td>
        <?php endif; ?>
```